# How do I combine this object "property list" outside of one declaration?

Tags: php, email, object

I'm using Eoghan's PHP Simple Mail script to send emails. I have an application which has two file fields, one is optional. I need to attach both files, only if both are provided.

The object is formatted strangely though:

```
$send   = $mailer->setTo('eoghan@example.com', 'John Smith')
         ->setSubject('Test Message')
         ->setFrom('no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com')
         ->send();
```

I'm not sure how to break this down into multiple lines. Right now it's all one big run on object oriented thing that I do not comprehend.

I assume it's something like this?

```
$send = $mailer->setTo($_TO_EMAIL, $_TO_NAME)
    ->setSubject($_SUBJECT)
    ->setFrom($_FROM_EMAIL, $_FROM_NAME);

// If true, send the mail
if ($my_var) $send .= $mailer->send();
```

EDIT: Also, what is this sort of behavior / syntax called, so I can learn it?

Comment: Try $send->send() without the .= concatenation, since the object has been assigned to $send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Each of the function calls (with the exception of `send()` returns a reference to the `$mailer` object. It's functionally equivalent to:

```
$mailer->setTo('john@example.com', 'John Smith');
$mailer->setSubject('Test Message');
$mailer->setFrom('no-reply@domain.com', 'Domain.com');
$send = $mailer->send();
```

To answer your question the last should look like this:

```
if ($my_var) $send = $mailer->send();
```

Comment: I actually went without `$mailer->` on the if statement section, as Scuzzy suggested, and that worked. Are both ways acceptable?